# Snakemake: create multiple wildcards for the same argument

Tags: linux, wildcard, snakemake, gatk

I am trying to run a `GenotypeGVCFs` on many vcf files. The command line wants every single `vcf` files be listed as:

```
java-jar GenomeAnalysisTK.jar -T GenotypeGVCFs \
-R my.fasta \
-V bob.vcf \
-V smith.vcf \
-V kelly.vcf \
-o {output.out}
```

How to do this in snakemake? This is my code, but I do not know how to create a wildcards for -V.

```
workdir: "/path/to/workdir/"

SAMPLES=["bob","smith","kelly]
print (SAMPLES)

rule all:
    input:
      "all_genotyped.vcf"

rule genotype_GVCFs:
    input:
        lambda w: "-V" + expand("{sample}.vcf", sample=SAMPLES)
    params:
        ref="my.fasta"
    output:
        out="all_genotyped.vcf"
    shell:
        """
        java-jar GenomeAnalysisTK.jar -T GenotypeGVCFs -R {params.ref} {input} -o {output.out}
        """
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are putting the cart before the horse. Wildcards are needed for rule generalization: you can define a pattern for a rule where wildcards are used to define generic parts. In your example there are no patterns: everything is defined by the value of `SAMPLES`. This is not a recommended way to use Snakemake; the pipeline should be defined by the filesystem: which files are present on your disk.

By the way, your code will not work, as the `input` shall define the list of filenames, while in your example you are (incorrectly) trying to define the strings like `"-V filename"`.

So, you have the output: `"all_genotyped.vcf"`. You have the input: `["bob.vcf", "smith.vcf", "kelly.vcf"]`. You don't even need to use a lambda here, as the input doesn't depend on any wildcard. So, you have:

```py
rule genotype_GVCFs:
    input:
        expand("{sample}.vcf", sample=SAMPLES)
    output:
        "all_genotyped.vcf"
    ...
```

Actually you don't even need `input` section. If you know for sure that the files from `SAMPLES` list exist, you may skip it.

The values for `-V` can be defined in params:

```py
rule genotype_GVCFs:
    #input:
    #    expand("{sample}.vcf", sample=SAMPLES)
    output:
        "all_genotyped.vcf"
    params:
        ref = "my.fasta",
        vcf = expand("-V {sample}", sample=SAMPLES)
    shell:
        """
        java-jar GenomeAnalysisTK.jar -T GenotypeGVCFs -R {params.ref} {params.vcf} -o {output}
        """
```

This should solve your issue, but I would advise you to rethink your solution. The use of `SAMPLE` list smells. Alternatively: do you really need Snakemake if you have all dependencies defined already?

Comment: thanks a lot! I have found out that this could be solved quite easily by creating a list of files... but this your solution is interesting and usefull for me also for the future + super explanations!